# Android Design library and support library error while including 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am adding a new feature for the already developed android application (Built in Eclipse). The feature is for getting google latitude and longitude using

```
   com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
```

here is my build.gradel,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myproject.activities"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

}

when i remove the `compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')` and add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` i get build error

```
    Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
```

here is my complete build error:

```html
C:\Users\maven\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-appinvite\8.4.0\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
C:\Users\maven\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(26, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(26, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(40, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
Error:(44, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
C:\Users\maven\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(128, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(126, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(125, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(131, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(128, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(126, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(125, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(131, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(217, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(217, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(128, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(126, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(125, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
C:\Users\maven\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\maven\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 6.737 secs
Information:116 errors
```

I don't seem to figure out why i am getting this error.

Comment: com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1 is the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all make your all tools to latest versions:

then add play-service library with version as :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
```

then

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.1'
```

and when you add library of play service from gradle, it throws multidex error as as new library addition have made play service library total method count more then 64K limit. so please follow steps from this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)